# JavaScript function. Returning number of times a word appears

Tags: javascript

I have the following question I just cannot work out:

> Write a function called countStr that takes two arguments (str and searchStr) and returns the number of times searchStr occurs in str. Check that it’s working, `console.log(countStr("Hello", "l"));` should log 2."

Comment: What is it about the question you don't understand? What have you tried already? If you've already tried some code post it in your question so we can try and help you. At the moment it sounds like you want us to solve the problem for you which isn't really what SO is for.

Answer (score 0):

To help with your homework:

```
var countStr = function(str, searchStr) {
  return str.match(new RegExp(searchStr, "g")).length;
}
```

This gives the number of Regular Expression occurrences in the string as an array. We return the length of an array as the count.

Comment: It would be nice to try and understand what it is about the question the OP doesn't understand first. And I bet he doesn't know what a regex is.

Answer (score 0):

`function countStr(str, searchStr) {
    var n = str.search(searchStr);
    return n;
}

document.write(countStr("Hello","l"));`

Comment: Sorry to everyone, it may have seemed like I was just trying to get you to do my coursework. I have now worked it out and above is my answer.